Why is my Angular EventEmitter not working with TemplatePortal from Angular CDK?
I'm working on an Angular project where I'm using Angular CDK's Overlay and TemplatePortal to display a dynamic menu. The menu should emit events when an option is selected, but the EventEmitter doesn't seem to work as expected.
Here's what I'm doing:

I create a component that uses Angular CDK's Overlay to open a menu.
The menu is defined in an ng-template and attached to the overlay
using TemplatePortal.
I want to emit events using EventEmitter when a menu item is clicked,
but the events don't seem to fire.

Here's the relevant code:

menu-example.component.ts



   import {
     Component,
     ViewChild,
     TemplateRef,
     ViewContainerRef,
     Output,
     EventEmitter,
   } from '@angular/core';
   import { Overlay, OverlayRef } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
   import { TemplatePortal } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
   
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-menu-example',
     templateUrl: './menu-example.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./menu-example.component.css'],
   })
   export class MenuExampleComponent {
     @ViewChild('menuTemplate', { read: TemplateRef }) menuTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;
   
     @Output() triggerOption = new EventEmitter<string>();
   
     private overlayRef!: OverlayRef;
   
     constructor(private overlay: Overlay, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
   
     openMenu(event: MouseEvent, control: any) {
      
       if (this.overlayRef) {
         this.overlayRef.dispose();
       }
   
      
       const positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
         .flexibleConnectedTo(event.target as HTMLElement)
         .withPositions([{
           originX: 'start',
           originY: 'bottom',
           overlayX: 'start',
           overlayY: 'top',
           offsetX: 0,
           offsetY: 8,
         }]);
   
       
       this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
         positionStrategy,
         hasBackdrop: true,
         backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
         panelClass: 'custom-panel-class',
       });
   
       
       const portal = new TemplatePortal(
         this.menuTemplate,
         this.viewContainerRef,
         { $implicit: control, component: this } 
       );
   
       this.overlayRef.attach(portal);
   
       
       this.overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => this.closeMenu());
     }
   
     closeMenu() {
       if (this.overlayRef) {
         this.overlayRef.dispose();
       }
     }
   
     openOptionsView(control: any) {
       console.log('Settings clicked for:', control);
       this.triggerOption.emit('Settings');
     }
   
     removeControl(control: any) {
       console.log('Remove clicked for:', control);
       this.triggerOption.emit('Remove');
     }
   }



menu-example.component.html


    <ng-template #menuTemplate let-control let-component="component">
      <div class="control-menu-bar">
        <button
          class="control-menu-bar-item"
          matTooltip="Settings"
          (click)="component.openOptionsView(control)"
        >
          <mat-icon>settings_suggest</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button
          class="control-menu-bar-item"
          matTooltip="Remove"
          (click)="component.removeControl(control)"
        >
          <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    
    <button (click)="openMenu($event, { name: 'Control 1' })">Open Menu</button>



Parent Component Code:


    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent',
      templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
    })
    export class ParentComponent {
      handleMenuOption(option: string) {
        console.log('Menu option selected:', option);
       
      }
    }



Parent Component HTML:


    <app-menu-example (triggerOption)="handleMenuOption($event)"></app-menu-example>


Question:

How can I ensure that the triggerOption EventEmitter emits events
correctly when using TemplatePortal?
Is there a specific way to manage context or binding issues when
using TemplatePortal in Angular CDK?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Created a stackblitz here and I can see from the browser console that your event bindings were working fine.

@Pieterjan Sorry mate, it works. I believe I didn't make the exact scenario I had. I had two divs on top of each other scenario explained in this link by JB Nizet link. I managed to fix it by using service instead.

The implicit prevented the component template reference variable for being initialized property, instead create two variables.
const portal = new TemplatePortal(
  this.menuTemplate,
  this.viewContainerRef,
  { control, component: this }
);

Stackblitz Demo

If you want to implement using $implicit you can pass them as properties of a single object.
const portal = new TemplatePortal(
  this.menuTemplate,
  this.viewContainerRef,
  { $implicit: { control, component: this } }
);

HTML:
<ng-template #menuTemplate let-item>
    <div class="control-menu-bar">
      <button
        class="control-menu-bar-item"
        matTooltip="Settings"
        (click)="item.component.openOptionsView(item.control)"
      >
        <mat-icon>settings_suggest</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button
        class="control-menu-bar-item"
        matTooltip="Remove"
        (click)="item.component.removeControl(item.control)"
      >
        <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon> 
      </button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  
  <button (click)="openMenu($event, { name: 'Control 1' })">Open Menu</button>

Stackblitz Demo
